# Integral Operator Theory on $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let K be the integral operator on l^2[0,1] defined by

itex(t) = \int_0^t (t-s)f(s)\,ds[/itex] where 0\leq t\leq 1

Show that ||K|| <1 and that

tex(t)= \int_0^t (((t-s)^(2n-1))/((2n-1)!))*(f(s))\,ds [/tex]

Hence solve for f which is an element of L^2[0,1] the integral equation

[tex]f(t) = g(t) + \int_0^t (t-s)f(s)\,ds [/tex]

where g is a given function in L^2[0,1]

Work done so far-

I have tried to maximise the inner product of  and on substitution of f(s) with

(a^2)(t-s)

and application of

||f(s)||2 =1

It is derived that

[tex]\int_0^1 (a^2)(t-s)^2\,ds = (a^2)[((t^2)*s-t(s^2)+(s^3)/3)][\tex] between 0 and 1.

Max is achieved on setting t=1, and it is derived that tex/3[tex] = [tex]||f(s)||^2[tex] = 1. So we find [tex]a = Sqrt[3][tex].

On further applying these findings into the original equation for (K(f))(t) get that

tex(t) = \int_0^t[(t-s)f(s)\,ds[tex] where 0<=t<=1

```
    = [tex]\int_0^1 (a)(t-s)^2\,dt = \sqrt{3}/3 =\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]} [tex] <1
```

And here as it was asked of me to show ||K||<1, BINGO!

From here on in I am cold, alone, thirsty and tired.

Any help will be appreciated. Sorry for all the horrific notation in advance! Mathematica users unite!!!!!

Comment: Would like to help you be warmer, etc. but I actually couldn't quite make my way thru your notation.  Can you rewrite this with latex?  See this site for assistance:http://www.physicsforums.com/showpost.php?p=3977517&postcount=3

Comment: I did as much as I could!

Comment: Thanks Yiorgos and Betty respectively. Needless to say I am absolutely clueless when it comes to Latex, but thanks Betty especially for providing an introduction. I've tried to put my point across more clearly (Dubious!) in Latex-speak but no cigar. Thanks again for your input! I'll practice before adding another question (and first answer) in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove $||K||<1$, we can do the following. Recalling the definition of the norm of an operator

> $$ ||K|| =\sup \frac{||Kf||_2}{||f||_2},  $$

we have

> $$||Kf||^2_2= \int_{0}^{1}|(Kf)(t)|^2dt = \int_{0}^{1}\Bigg|\int_{0}^{t}(t-s)f(s)ds   \bigg|^2dt $$

Now, Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies
$$ \Bigg|\int_{0}^{t}(t-s)f(s)ds   \bigg| \leq \int_{0}^{t}|t-s||f(s)|ds = \sqrt{\int_{0}^{t}(t-s)^2ds} \, \sqrt{\int_{0}^{t}|f(s)|^2 ds} =\frac{t^{3/2}}{\sqrt{3}}\,||f||_2   $$

$$ \implies \Bigg|\int_{0}^{t}(t-s)f(s)ds   \bigg|^2 \leq \frac{t^3 }{{3}} ||f||^2_2 $$

$$ \implies ||Kf||^2_2 \leq \frac{||f||^2_2}{3}\int_{0}^{1}t^3 dt= \frac{||f||^2_2}{12}$$

> $$ \implies \frac{||Kf||_2}{||f||_2} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} \implies ||K|| =\sup \frac{||Kf||_2}{||f||_2} < 1. $$

**To find $K^n$**, you need to use the following fact for integral operators

> $$ LK \equiv \int_{0}^{t}L(s,v)K(v,t) dv $$

Comment: Thank you for your input Mhenni. It never occurred to me to apply Cauchy Schwarz. I don't believe I have come across your final statement in my studies, but I will try my best nevertheless. Thanks a great deal!

Comment: @willswarriors: you are very welcome. By the way, what course is this?

Comment: I'm currently undergoing PUNCTUAL DIALYSIS (Hint: The reason's in the rhyme).